# How can I properly overload a WebAPI 2 Controller with multiple collection parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to design my WebAPI controller with overloaded Get methods that will be selected based on the parameters a user provides.  I'm able to get this to work properly in some cases, but when I have multiple collection parameters on a method my controller is no longer able to select the correct route, even if I am not specifying both collections.

For example the following set up works:

```
[RoutePrefix("data/stock")]
public class StockDataController 
    : ApiController {

    private readonly IDataProvider<StockDataItem> _dataProvider;

    public StockDataController() {
        _dataProvider = new StockDataProvider();
    }

    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<StockDataItem> Get([FromUri] string[] symbols) {
        // Return current stock data for the provided symbols
    }

    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<StockDataItem> Get([FromUri] string[] symbols, DateTime time) {
        // Return stock data at a specific time for the provided symbols
    }

}
```

**Selects Method 1**

GET http://server/data/stock/?symbols[]=GOOG&symbols[]=MSFT

**Selects Method 2**

GET http://server/data/stock/?symbols[]=GOOG&symbols[]=MSFT&time=2015-01-01

Once I add the following overload, then everything breaks down:

```
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Get(
        [FromUri] string[] symbols, [FromUri] string[] fields) {
        // Return specified stock data fields for the specified symbols
    }
```

I would expect the following request to select Method 3:

GET http://server/data/stock/?symbols[]=GOOG&symbols[]=MSFT&fields[]=Price&fields[]=Volume

Instead I receive the error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: Get on type
>   StockDataController Get on type StockDataController

Is it possible to have multiple collection parameters in this way?  If so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `RoutePrefix`, and then adding specific routes to the actions (`data/stock/{symbols}` and `data/stock/{symbols}/{fields}`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an optional parameter in your REST service.

Just use your time variable as nulleable: DateTime? time

```
public IEnumerable<StockDataItem> Get([FromUri] string[] symbols, DateTime? time) {
    // Return stock data at a specific time for the provided symbols
}
```

Now you can call your service as:

GET http://server/data/stock/?symbols[]=GOOG&symbols[]=MSFT

or

GET http://server/data/stock/?symbols[]=GOOG&symbols[]=MSFT&time=2015-01-01

Comment: The scenario you outlined already works properly using method overloading.  The only problem I am having is when I want to do the same thing but with two parameters of type `string[]`.  I know I could solve my problem with a single method and optional parameters, but I'm trying to avoid a bunch of `if(p1.HasValue && !p2.HasValue)` logic.  Also I'd like to understand more about why only one of my scenarios works when they are both fundamentally the same.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstand your question :( 

But that behavior is because webapi treats all reference type parameters as optionals parameters. 

So, if you call: 
GET server/data/stock/?symbols[]=GOOG&symbols[]=MSFT 

it can't undestand if you are calling:
`public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromUri] string[] symbols)` or `public IEnumerable<dynamic> Get([FromUri]string[] symbols, [FromUri] string[] fields)` because `fields` can be `null`

And thats why you get this exception after add the new method